# Port in IPAddress

Tags: c#, ip-address

I get a string ,representing ip address .It has format ip:port
I need to generate IPAddress .Will use for that :

```
public static IPAddress Parse(
    string ipString
)
```

The IPAddress which I need to get should not contain the data regarding a port.
Does `parse` support that? If not how is it possible to done?

Comment: Is this always an IPv4 address?

Comment: I don't know what an IPv6 address with a port even looks like outside a URL - can you give an example? And will there *always* be a port?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: As a side note, [Section 6 of RFC5952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-6) covers a few ways on port notation for IPv6.

Comment: @NumLock: Ick. I guess it will depend on the format then... and the OP has gone quiet :(

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to absolutely know whether you are **ALWAYS** getting a port along with your `IP` or not. If you are always getting a port then you can always use **Jon's** code and get rid of the part after the last colon.

The `ipString` then you can pass on to the `IPAddress.TryParse` function to get the IPAddress object.

The `IPAddress.Parse` function will give you an exception if the `ipString` for whatever reason is not in a correct format.

Now why do you have to absolutely know about the existence of the `port` in the string.
Let me give you an example:

`::213` - An absolutely valid IPV6 address. But it has two different meanings:

If you already know there must be a port then this translates to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:213`.

But if you do not know then this can also mean `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:213`.
Note there is one less segment as compared to the above one. A valid IPV6 always has 8 segments, the example i am giving is the shorthand notation for a IPV6 address.

Let's say you **do not know** whether you would be getting a port in your string or not. Then you **MUST** always assume that IPV6 addresses would be in the `long notation`.
In which case you can check for the count of colons present like so (this is only for IPV6): (Very crude example)

```
 int colonCount = ipV6String.Count(c => c == ':');
 int dotCount = ipV6String.Count(c=> c== '.');
 if (((colonCount == 7) && (dotCount == 3)) ||
                 ((colonCount == 8) && (dotCount == 0)))
 {
    //Port is present in the string
    //Extract port using LastIndexOf
 }
 else
 {
    //Port NOT present
 }
```

To make this workable for `IPV4` just check for `3 dots` and `1 colon` as well

Some examples of valid `IPAddresses` (without port information)

**IPV4**

```
x.x.x.x
```

**IPV6**

```
x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x
x:x:x:x:x:x:d.d.d.d
: : (short hand notation meaning all the segments are 0s)
x: x: : (means that the last six segments are 0s)
: : x : x (means that the first six segments are 0s)
x : x: : x : x (means the middle four segments are 0s)
```

Please check these following links as well for information about IPAddress formats:

`http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dsichelp/ds8000ic/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.storage.ssic.help.doc%2Ff2c_internetprotocol_3st92x.html`

`http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ts3500tl/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc%2Fopg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_addresses.html`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's there's *always* a port and it's *always* represented by `:<port number>`, you can just unconditionally remove the part after the last colon:

```
int portStart = ipString.LastIndexOf(':');
ipString = ipString.Substring(0, portStart);
```

I would expect that to work with IPv6 as well, unless your IPv6 "address and port" format doesn't use a colon - as is feasible with [RFC5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-6). Basically to do this well, you'll need to have more of an idea of the format you'll be receiving.