# IPAddress.TryParse returns false

Tags: c#, ip-address, tryparse

I have a string with IP Address which is

```
clientId = "172.19.200.29:10308"
```

I need to generate IPAddress  object from it.Tried the following

```
    IPAddress clientIpAddr;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(clientId, out clientIpAddr)) //<-returns false
//clientIpAddr is null
```

What could be wrong

Comment: I think you need to remove the port by hand.

Comment: Are you looking for an IPEndPoint? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.ipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please have a look at the answer to your previous question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588594/port-in-ipaddress/22589478#22589478` for an explanation of IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. The port needs to be extracted out before TryParse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an IP address, it's an IP address and port

try

```
if (IPAddress.TryParse(clientId.Split(':')[0], out clientIpAddr))
```

If you want IPv6 support

```
 var arr = clientId.Split(':');
 clientId = arr.Length <= 2 ? arr[0] : string.Join(":", arr.Take(8).ToArray());
 if (IPAddress.TryParse(clientId, out clientIpAddr))
```

Comment: what happens if the address will be ipv6?

Comment: even can`t be compiled

Answer (score 3):

The [IPAddress class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **should only contain the IP** (without the port).
You might be confused with the [IPEndPoint class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Net.IPEndPoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which contains both IP and port:

Instantiate the IPAddress object as the following:

```
string clientId = "172.19.200.29:10308";
IPAddress clientIpAddr;
var success = IPAddress.TryParse(clientId.Split(':')[0], out clientIpAddr);
```

If required, you can instantiate the IPEndPoint as the following:

```
// Assuming that both ip and port are valid.
int port = int.Parse(clientId.Split(':')[1]);

var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(clientIpAddr, port);
```